# Tag synonym request: [google-mail] -> [gmail]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

There are currently 1252 questions on SO tagged [gmail](/questions/tagged/gmail). There were 7 questions tagged [google-mail](/questions/tagged/google-mail) asked this year, some of which were already tagged [gmail](/questions/tagged/gmail) as well. I already took the liberty of retagging those to [gmail](/questions/tagged/gmail), but I think that [google-mail](/questions/tagged/google-mail) should be a synonym for [gmail](/questions/tagged/gmail).