# Tag synonym request [dart] -> [google-dart]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

With the introduction of [Google Dart](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/10/dart-language-for-structured-web.html) I think it might be useful to have a [dart](/questions/tagged/dart) tag synonym for the existing [google-dart](/questions/tagged/google-dart) tag.

**Edit:**

The reason why I picked [google-dart](/questions/tagged/google-dart) as the master is because I searched the [synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) for `google`. There I noticed the following existing synonym -> master relations:

- [google+](/questions/tagged/google%2b) -> [google-plus](/questions/tagged/google-plus)
- [gmaps](/questions/tagged/gmaps) -> [google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps)
- [appengine](/questions/tagged/appengine) -> [google-app-engine](/questions/tagged/google-app-engine)
- ...

**Another edit:**

There are exceptions for [gmail](/questions/tagged/gmail), [adsense](/questions/tagged/adsense), [gwt](/questions/tagged/gwt), [guice](/questions/tagged/guice) and some more. So I'm not so sure anymore about which should be master/synonym.

Comment: Interesting that it's not the other way around. We don't use `[oracle-java]`, `[springsource-groovy]`, or `[microsoft-c#]` for those languages.

Comment: Actually, looking again, it looks like `[dart]` already has the majority tag share (97 tags) to `[google-dart]`'s 4 tags. I'd recommend the synonym go the other way. `[google-dart]` -> `[dart]`. Although maybe that's what you're asking. I always get confused trying to understand the directionality of synonyms.

Comment: @Rob a search for `[dart]` returns me exactly one question at this moment.

Comment: Erps. I did a stupid there and just counted the results for a search for "dart".

Comment: I guess I'd still vote for `[google-dart]` -> `[dart]`, for consistency.

Comment: I'd agree with Rob.  `[dart]` should be the *master* tag.  `[google-dart]` should be a *synonym* for `[dart]`, such that an attempt to add a `[google-dart]` tag would cause the `[dart]` tag to be added instead.  Also, it's now 5 [[tag:google-dart]] questions to one [[tag:dart]] question - We'd better make this choice before it gets out of hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me put my two cents. There is already another programming language created by Google: "The Go Programming Language". And SO [uses](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info) the [go](/questions/tagged/go) tag for it, and NOT the [google-go](/questions/tagged/google-go).

I think it will be more consistent if we use the same approach for the Dart, leaving google-dart as a synonym: [google-dart](/questions/tagged/google-dart) -> [dart](/questions/tagged/dart).

Answer (score 5):

My vote is actually for the opposite:

[google-dart](/questions/tagged/google-dart) > [dart](/questions/tagged/dart)

Making [dart](/questions/tagged/dart) the primary tag, for the same reason we don't have [oracle-java](/questions/tagged/oracle-java) or [microsoft-.net](/questions/tagged/microsoft-.net).

---

Potential conflicts:

- [this operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Access_in_Real_Time). This OS might get [emc-dart](/questions/tagged/emc-dart) or something.
- [DoubleClick DART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DoubleClick) - Interesting that Google has two products named "DART/Dart". Seems to only be [one existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532093/is-there-an-ajax-service-for-doubleclick-dart) at the moment.

I'd argue that the programming language has more potential for higher question volume. Also, it's more programming-related than the conflicts. These reasons might warrant it earning the master tag.

Comment: When searching the [synonyms page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) for `google` you'll see that google+ -> google-plus, gmaps -> google-maps, appengine -> google-app-engine, ...

Comment: @Psy - You'll also see google-mail -> gmail [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108884/tag-synonym-request-google-mail-gmail).  Your examples are to remove the un-searchable `+` symbol from a tag, to change a non-standard 'gmaps' name to something standard (and `[maps]` would be ambigous), and a non-hyphenated name to the hyphenated, official version.  I don't think that `[dart]` warrants a Google prefix.

Comment: @Rob, I agree that since Google themselves is calling it Dart, we should probably use that tag (since there aren't any big conflicts).