# Should the Dart and Google-Dart tags be merged?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag synonym request [dart] -> [google-dart]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108888/tag-synonym-request-dart-google-dart)

They're basically speaking about the same language and divides the users.

Thoughts?